# Java exec can't run program, error = 2

Tags: java, eclipse, r, runtime.exec

I'm trying to run R.exe from a Java application with Java exec.
R is in the Environment Variables and if I execute it from cmd with "R" command it works.
If I execute an example instruction in Java and try to open notepad it works:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec("notepad");
```

But when I try to open R with this instruction:

```
Process p = rt.exec("R");
```

it gives me this kind of error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "R": CreateProcess error=2
```

what could be? why cant I open R from Java?

Comment: Is it on your `PATH`, this R.exe?

Comment: its in the Environment Variables

Comment: @Enrico Tedeschi Is "R" set in the `Path` of a specific user or is it set system wide ? Usually when you run a program from an IDE is run as administrator so if "R" is set only in the `Path` of a specific user that can be the problem.

Comment: its in the system Path, if I execute it from cmd it works in every directory. It doesnt work only in Java

Comment: It is blind shot but could you try something like `"cmd /C R"` as command?

Comment: I've tried with this: `Process p = rt.exec("cmd /C R");` and it doesnt show me the error as before, I can catch it and it print me this:
`'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: and of course if I try it from cmd it works perfectly @Pshemo

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the Windows `PATH` includes the directory that `R` resides in for this to work

`CreateProcess error=2` indicates the file can not be found

Comment: it works if I execute it directly from cmd in each directory I'm. It just doesnt work in Java with exec command

Comment: what about using ProcessBuilder `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("R", "", "", "", "");Process p = pb.start();`